# Is there a broadcast priority in Blackberry similar to Android for received SMS?

Tags: blackberry, sms

We are trying to build a Blackberry application to filter incoming SMS (s).
We have been successful in intercepting the message using Datagram / MessageConnection.
However, by the time we receive the message in our listening thread and process it, the message has already reached the SMS Inbox. This is defeating the purpose of intercepting. Also, Blackberry does not allow reading/writing/deleting SMS from SMS Inbox. Therefore, once the SMS reaches the Inbox, there is nothing that can be done to remove it.

The Firewall filter works pretty well for blocking SMS. However, there is no API to access Firewall settings.

I think the only option would be to set the listener in such a way that it receives the SMS before the native Inbox. But we are not able to find any documentation around this.
Any pointers for resolving this issue will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to programatically prevent an SMS from going into the inbox is to send it to a non-zero port and have a process registered to listen to that port. SMSs sent only to port 0 will be delivered to the inbox regardless of what a listener may do.